# is it possible to fix the height of a tikz box same?

Tags: tikz-pgf, height

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\newcommand{\buttonfont}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\btn}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) [draw, rounded corners] {\buttonfont#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\btn{--}

\vspace{2pc}

\btn{x\textsuperscript{2}}

\end{document}
```

Output comes no issues, but is it possible to fix the height of the box should be consistent in all occurrences?

Please advise.

Comment: It should also be noted that \btn{--} and \btn{x\textsuperscript{2}} look different than \buttonfont{--} and \buttonfont{x\textsuperscript{2}} in terms of the space between the characters and the font used for 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the node option `minimum height`. For example,

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\newcommand{\buttonfont}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\btn}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) [draw, rounded corners,minimum height=2em] {\buttonfont{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\btn{--} \btn{x\textsuperscript{2}}

\end{document}
```